# How to convert intervals with value to individual position level in R

Tags: r

I struggle a bit with following problem:
I have table A (below) and I would like to merge/reduce/covert intervals defined in there to individual positions like in table B by calculating sum (values in table A) of overlapping positions in intervals (start and end  of each interval in table A) if any or just give value if no overlapping positions or 0 if no interval for that position.  I would  prefer solution for that problem in R.  I would really appreciate your help.

Table A

```
ID Start End Value
1  1      5     9
2  3      7     5
3  5      9    13
4  11     15    1
5  12     16   18
6  14     18   21
```

Convert to this Table B

```
Position Value
1        9
2        9
3        14
4        14
5        27
6        18
7        18
8        13
9        13
10       0
11       15
12       33
13       33
14       54
15       54
16       39
17       21
18       21
```

Comment: In a similar (but not identical) question, I found a solution using the `IRanges` package from *Bioconductor*, see the [Vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/IRanges/inst/doc/IRangesOverview.pdf). Perhaps, the `Rle` class  in `IRanges` could be your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very straight forward way but it gets the job done:

```
df<-structure(list(ID = 1:6, Start = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 14L), 
                   End = c(5L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 18L), 
                   Value = c(9L, 5L, 13L, 1L, 18L, 21L)), .Names = c("ID", "Start", "End", "Value"),
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                -6L))
# create list matrix for each grouping
s1<-lapply(1:6, function(i) {matrix(c(df[i,2]:df[i,3], rep(df[i,4], (df[i,3]-df[i,2]+1))), nrow = (df[i,3]-df[i,2])+1)})
s2<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, s1))

#sum all of the like positions
library(dplyr)
wgaps<-summarise(group_by(s2, V1), sum(V2))

#create sequence with no gaps in it and match
nogaps<-data.frame(Position=seq(min(wgaps$V1), max(wgaps$V1)))
nogaps<-left_join(nogaps, wgaps, by=c("Position"= "V1"))
names(nogaps)<-c("Position", "value")   #rename
nogaps$value[is.na(nogaps$value)]<-0    #remove 0
```